# Bash ping script with LCD error message errors

Tags: c, bash, debian, ping

I am working in Debian and I am trying to write a script that will ping a host (192.168.10.30) every 10 seconds.

Whenever the ping is not successful, I want to have the message "VPN Lost" be displayed on my LCD screen. Once the ping is successful again the "VPN Lost" message will disappear from my LCD screen, and the screen will display "STS300".

The code below keeps giving me an error when I try to compile it, and I do not understand why. (The code compiles fine, but once I added in the code for the ping it won't compile). The code that is giving me trouble is between the lines `lcd_command(LINE_3);` and `lcd_command(LINE_4);`

I am fairly new to this...

The errors I am getting are...

> lcdSignal.c: In function 'main': lcdSignal.c:190:10: error: expected
>   '(' before 'true'
>
> lcdSignal.c:190:10: error: 'true' undeclared (first use in this
>   function)
>
> lcdSignal.c:190:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only
>   once for each function it appears in
>
> lcdSignal.c:191:3: error: 'ping' undeclared (first use in this
>   function)
>
> lcdSignal.c:191:12: error: too many decimal points in number
>
> lcdSignal.c:191:9: error: 'c1' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> lcdSignal.c:191:12: error: expected ';' before numeric constant
>
> lcdSignal.c:192:3: error: expected 'while' before 'lcd_writechars'
>
> lcdSignal.c:193:7: error: expected '(' before '[' token
>
> lcdSignal.c:193:12: error: '$' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> lcdSignal.c:193:19: error: unknown type name 'then'
>
> lcdSignal.c:194:18: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...'
>   before string constant
>
> lcdSignal.c:195:3: error: 'fi' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> lcdSignal.c:196:9: error: expected ';' before numeric constant

If someone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it!!!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "evgpio.h"
#include "STSConfig.h"  // This file is where the strings are modified

void lcd_init(void);
void lcd_wait(void);
void lcd_command(uint16_t);
void lcd_writechars(unsigned char *dat);

// These are microsecond delays
#define SETUP   1
#define PULSE   2
#define HOLD    1

#define LINE_1      0x80                // beginning position of LCD line 1
#define LINE_2      0xC0                // beginning position of LCD line 2
#define LINE_3      0x94                // beginning position of LCD line 3
#define LINE_4      0xD4                // beginning position of LCD line 4

#define LCD_D0      74
#define LCD_D1      75
#define LCD_D2      72
#define LCD_D3      73
#define LCD_D4      70
#define LCD_D5      71
#define LCD_D6      68
#define LCD_D7      69
#define LCD_EN      64
#define LCD_WR      65
#define LCD_RS      66
#define LCD_BIAS    67

void lcd_write(uint8_t out)
{
    evsetdata(LCD_D0, out & (1 << 0));
    evsetdata(LCD_D1, out & (1 << 1));
    evsetdata(LCD_D2, out & (1 << 2));
    evsetdata(LCD_D3, out & (1 << 3));
    evsetdata(LCD_D4, out & (1 << 4));
    evsetdata(LCD_D5, out & (1 << 5));
    evsetdata(LCD_D6, out & (1 << 6));
    evsetdata(LCD_D7, out & (1 << 7));
}

void lcd_ddr(uint8_t out)
{
    evsetddr(LCD_D0, out & (1 << 0));
    evsetddr(LCD_D1, out & (1 << 1));
    evsetddr(LCD_D2, out & (1 << 2));
    evsetddr(LCD_D3, out & (1 << 3));
    evsetddr(LCD_D4, out & (1 << 4));
    evsetddr(LCD_D5, out & (1 << 5));
    evsetddr(LCD_D6, out & (1 << 6));
    evsetddr(LCD_D7, out & (1 << 7));
}

uint8_t lcd_read()
{
    uint8_t out = 0;
    out |= (evgetin(LCD_D0) << 0);
    out |= (evgetin(LCD_D1) << 1);
    out |= (evgetin(LCD_D2) << 2);
    out |= (evgetin(LCD_D3) << 3);
    out |= (evgetin(LCD_D4) << 4);
    out |= (evgetin(LCD_D5) << 5);
    out |= (evgetin(LCD_D6) << 6);
    out |= (evgetin(LCD_D7) << 7);

    return out;
}

void lcd_enpulse()
{
    usleep(SETUP);
    evsetdata(LCD_EN, 1);
    usleep(PULSE);
    evsetdata(LCD_EN, 0);
    usleep(HOLD);
}

void lcd_init(void)
{
    evgpioinit();
    // Data lines to inputs, control lines to outputs
    lcd_ddr(0x0);
    evsetddr(LCD_EN, 1);
    evsetddr(LCD_RS, 1);
    evsetddr(LCD_WR, 1);

    // Set LCD_EN and LCD_RS low
    evsetdata(LCD_EN, 0);
    evsetdata(LCD_RS, 0);
    // Set LCD_WR high
    evsetdata(LCD_WR, 1);

    usleep(15000);
    lcd_command(0x38); // two rows, 5x7, 8 bit
    usleep(4100);
    lcd_command(0x38); // two rows, 5x7, 8 bit
    usleep(100);
    lcd_command(0x38); // two rows, 5x7, 8 bit
    lcd_command(0x6); // cursor increment mode
    lcd_wait();
    //lcd_command(0x1); // clear display
    // lcd_wait();
    //  lcd_command(0xc); // display on, blink off, cursor off
    //   lcd_wait();
    lcd_command(0x2); // return home

    evsetddr(LCD_BIAS, 1);
    evsetdata(LCD_BIAS, 0);
}

void lcd_wait(void)
{
    uint8_t in;
    int i, dat, tries = 0;
    lcd_ddr(0x0);
    do {
        // step 1, apply only RS & WR
        evsetdata(LCD_RS, 0);
        evsetdata(LCD_WR, 1); // low for write
        lcd_enpulse();
        usleep(1);
    } while (in & 0x80 && tries++ < 5);
}

void lcd_command(uint16_t cmd)
{
    lcd_ddr(0xff);

    lcd_write(cmd);
    evsetdata(LCD_WR, 0);
    evsetdata(LCD_RS, 0);

    lcd_enpulse();
}


void lcd_writechars(unsigned char *dat)
{
    int i;

    do {
        lcd_wait();
        lcd_ddr(0xff);
        evsetdata(LCD_RS, 1);
        evsetdata(LCD_WR, 0); // active low
        lcd_write(*dat++);
        lcd_enpulse();
    } while (*dat);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *temp = argv[1];
    float sigStn = atof(temp);
    float numBuf = (((sigStn-(-120))/(-70-(-120)))*100);
    char buf[48];
    if (numBuf >=9 && numBuf<=99) {
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "    Signal=  %0.0f",numBuf);
        strcat(buf,"%   ");
    } else {
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "    Signal=   %0.0f",numBuf);
        strcat(buf,"%   ");
    }

    lcd_init();
    lcd_command(LINE_1);
    lcd_writechars(STS);
    lcd_command(LINE_2);
    if (numBuf > 100)
        lcd_writechars("    Signal= 100%     ");
    else if(numBuf<0){
        lcd_writechars("    Reconnecting   ");
        // lcd_writechars("   Signal =   0%   ");
    } else
        lcd_writechars(buf);        
    lcd_command(LINE_3);
{while true; do
ping -c1 192.168.10.30 2>&1 /dev/null;   //VPN IP
lcd_writechars("STS300");}
{if [[ ! $? ]]; then
lcd_writechars("VPN Lost");
fi;
sleep 10;
}
lcd_command(LINE_4);
lcd_writechars(BBPN);

    return;

while (!feof(stdin)) {
    unsigned char buf[512];
    int i = 0;
    lcd_wait();
    if (i) {
        // XXX: this seek addr may be different for different
        // LCD sizes!  -JO
        lcd_command(0xa8); // set DDRAM addr to second row
    } else
        lcd_command(0x2); // return home
    i = i ^ 0x1;
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
        unsigned int len;
        buf[0x27] = 0;
        len = strlen(buf);
        if (buf[len - 1] == '\n') buf[len - 1] = 0;
            lcd_writechars(buf);
        }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a very odd mash-up of C and bash shell programming. You started out in C, then around line 190 broke right out into bash shell. C doesn't understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines of code in your program aren't C at all. They look like a fragment of shell script:

```
lcd_command(LINE_3);
{while true; do
ping -c1 192.168.10.30 2>&1 /dev/null;   //VPN IP
lcd_writechars("STS300");}
{if [[ ! $? ]]; then
lcd_writechars("VPN Lost");
fi;
sleep 10;
}
```

This won't work. Rewrite this code in C. (The `system()` function may be helpful.)